# Hidden Objects Effecting Render Speeds

Tags: rendering

I am try to reduce render times as much as possible so I have tinkered around to reduce. However, I have observed that **the longest portion of my render actually comes from the tessellation and BVH calculations of objects that are turned OFF for render?** This would change my render speeds from an hour and a half to about 5 minutes if I can resolve.

Has anyone had this issue, and found a solution? I have tried just about everything besides deleting the hidden objects from my scene.

Comment: Have you tried moving them into a seperate collection? There's a comprehensive video about collections and render layers [here](https://youtu.be/8_o1MywoJhc) which might help.

Comment: @JohnEason Every object has there own collection and each collection in unticked.

Comment: I'd still suggest you watch the tutorial that I llinked to in my previous comment.